# Is $A^2 + (A^2)^t$ Positive Semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$ of size $n\times n$, which need not be symmetric, $A^2 + (A^2)^t$ (where $t$ denotes transpose) is certainly symmetric. Is it positive semidefinite?

Comment: No. The condition that $B=A^2$ is almost no restriction on $B$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Matrices_with_distinct_eigenvalues

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no. Example:
$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$